# How to replace " \ " with " \\ " in java

Tags: java, regex, string, backslash

I tried to break the string into arrays and replace `\` with `\\` , but couldn't do it, also I tried String.replaceAll something like this `("\","\\");`.

I want to supply a path to JNI and it reads only in this way.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Don't use [`String.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in this case - that's specified in terms of regular expressions, which means you'd need even more escaping. This should be fine:

```
String escaped = original.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Note that the backslashes are doubled due to being in Java string literals - so the *actual* strings involved here are "single backslash" and "double backslash" - not double and quadruple.

[`replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) works on simple strings - no regexes involved.

Comment: This adds four slashes like this \\\\ for me

Comment: @Jamesandresakis: It's hard to tell what you're doing wrong with so little information. My guess is that you're looking at the string in a debugger, where it may be escaping it for you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `replaceAll`:

```
String escaped = original.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to supply a path to JNI and it reads only in this way.

That's not right. You only need double backslashes in literal strings that you declare in a programming language. You never have to do this substitution at runtime. You need to rethink why you're doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be quite an adventure to deal with the "\" since it is considered as an escape character in Java. You always need to "\" a "\" in a String. But the fun begins when you want to use a "\" in regex expression, because the "\" is an escape character in regex too. So for a single "\" you need to use "\\" in a regex expression.

here is the link where i found this information: https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0476.html

I had to convert '\' to '\\'. I found somewhere that we can use:

```
filepathtext = filepathtext.replace("\\","\\\\");
```

and it works.
Given below is the image of how I implemented it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVjk6.png