# How to replace '\' by '\\' in java string?

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I want to replace a backslash character `\` by double backslash character `\\` from a string in Java but the replace() method does not seem to work. It gives an arguments mismatch error. I think it does not work with special characters. Any get around to this?

Here is my code snippet:

```
String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Locate Java Documentation Folder");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            JTextField jtfFileLocation=new JTextField();
            jtfFileLocation.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath()+fileSeparator);
            String filePath=jtfFileLocation.getText();
            filePath.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
            System.out.println(filePath);
        } else {

        }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: Did you really search ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535317/how-to-replace-with-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're most probably not escaping your backslashes correctly:

```
String newString = oldString.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

One literal backslash has to be encoded by two backslash characters. Be glad that it's not a regex you're dealing with:

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Comment: Only the first parameter for the `replaceAll` method is a regex. The replacement would still be `"\\\\"`.

Comment: @Lonenebula: No, the backslash is still a special character in a regex replacement string and needs to be escaped. Try it.

Comment: You are completely right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Tim Pietzcker. Actually what I am trying to do is: I take a directry path from JFileChooser and hold its path in a string variable, and when I use that path in stream variable it gives me an error. When I hardcode the file path by replacing a single slash by double slash then my program works. Your replace method is still not replacing the single slash by double slash. Thanks much for your help

Comment: @user1515601: Can you post the code that's not working for you?

Comment: Can't post the code of whole application but can post a snippet where I take in the file path dynamically. Please see the edit of the question.

Comment: Done with that. Thanks for your answers. I needed to declare a new string variable as String variables are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `String newString = originalString.replace("\\", "\\\\");`