# Escaping $ with \$

Tags: java, regex

I need to escape the `$` and therefore I need to replace all occurrences of `$` with `\$`

So I wrote this method:

```
// String#replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
public String escape$(String str) {
    // the first \\$ to escape it in regular expression
    // the second is a normal String so \\$ should mean \$
    return str.replaceAll("\\$", "\\$");
}


String s = "$some$$text here";
System.out.println(escape$(s));
```

Before I submitted for production use, I thought hmmm let's test that even though I was certain it should work. And so I did...

Well you guessed it. It doesn't work! It returns the same thing!

```
// expected result of the above: \$some\$\$text here
// reality: $some$$text here
```

So why doesn't this work?!

Comment: what do you expect `"\\$", "\\$` to do? Find "soemthing", and then replace it with the exact SAME "something"? You need to do `\\\\$` for the replacement.

Comment: Why are you using `replaceAll` rather than `replace`? `replaceAll` is more complex due to using regular expressions - which are causing you problems here. Just `return str.replace("$", "\\$");` should be fine... As an aside, I'd strongly recommend avoiding using `$` in your method name. From the JLS: "The $ sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems."

Comment: Why not just do `str.replace("$","\\$");`?

Comment: @MarcB no Marc, please read the comments in the method

Comment: Just because your comment states something doesn't make it the case. From `Matcher.replaceAll`: "Note that backslashes (`\`) and dollar signs (`$`) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string. Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535317/how-to-replace-with-in-java

Comment: I didn't know that `replace` replaces all!

Answer (score 4):

You need to double-escape the replacement.

You probably don't want to use `replaceAll`, as you'd actually need to double-double escape it, but you're not using regular expressions here.

Instead, you can just use `replace`, which takes literals (and uses `replaceAll` in the background, with quoted values - see [Matcher#quoteReplacement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement%28java.lang.String%29)).

Here are two examples:

```
System.out.println("$".replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$"));
System.out.println("$".replace("$", "\\$"));
```

**Output**

```
\$
\$
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret that would return a non-escaped `$`.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: No, it's not. Backslash and dollar still have special meaning in replacement strings. Read the docs for `Matcher.replaceAll`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were referring to the escapement in the first part, not the second one. My bad, I didn't read it well.

Comment: I've been programming in Java for 3 years, never thought that `replace` can actually replace all when there is a method `replaceAll`

Comment: @rz3r0 confusing isn't it :D

Comment: Your’re not the first. After 17 years I still have to check with the docs each time.

Answer (score 0):

For Java regex, it's not just that you have to *double escape* a string for the language,
which always has to be done.

It's that you have to escape the dollar sign for the engine as well to
***distinguish it from a capture variable***.

The replace string is actually a template for a string formatter.

Always write the replacement text in it's raw form first.
The *raw* form is what is presented to the engine as a *template* for the formatter.

Raw:  `\\` + `\$` <- the engine parses this as `\` + `$` (two separate literals)

Combined Raw: `\\\$`

Finally, for the language, just escape the escapes.

Stringed: `"\\\\\\$"`